# loop in bash script is stopping abruptly

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a bash script which runs a node script periodically. It runs well for some time but abruptly stops.

```
i=0
t=$((6 * 60 * 7)) 
while [ $i -lt $t ]; do 
  /Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.0.0/bin/node --no-warnings /Users/xxx/code/xxx/src/xxx/xxx.js >> /Users/xxx/logs/log.log 
  sleep 10
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
  now=$(date +"%T")
  echo $i $t $now 
done
```

it is written to run each 10 seconds for 7 hrs. But it hardly runs 30 mins and abruptly stops.

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting on it? Does it exit, or hang? Does it run with `-e` (/`errexit`) or any other nondefault modes set? If you run it with `bash -x`, what does the execution trace show leading up to it stopping?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better construction for a loop like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<t; i++)); do
  your_command_or_function
  sleep 10
  printf "%s %s %(%T)T" $i $t -1
done
```